# How can I rename all Replays in the Sc2 folder?

Tags: starcraft-2

I started using [Sc2gears](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/) to analyse my replays.

the naming in the replay folder is `/D-</p(/r-/B-/W)>-/n./e` which results for example in `2013-09-03 22-21-28-Player1name(T-B-N) vs Rubo77(Z-U-N)-Polar Night LE (5).SC2Replay`

Now I would like to rename all my existing replays in the same manner, but as default only new replays are stored in the Sc2gears replay archive folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the section [here](https://sites.google.com/site/sc2gears/how-to-use-sc2gears#TOC-Auto-save-and-auto-rename-my-replays) on how to batch rename replays.

> List the replays of a replay source or replay list (by double clicking on them in the navigation tree), select the replays you want to rename (or press CTRL+A to select all replays), then right click and choose "Rename replays..."